# How to use Image() in Swift Playgrounds for IPad

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-playground

How can I use an Image with SwiftUI in Swift Playgrounds for IPad.

Comment: What research have you done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is what I did and worked for the iPad:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Image {
  // usage: Image(name: "imageNameHere.jpg")
  public init(name:String) {
    self.init(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: name)) 
  }
}
```

or

```
extension Image {
  // usage: Image(name: "imageNameHere.jpg")
  public init(name: String) {
    self.init(uiImage: UIImage(named: name)!)
  }
}
```

PS: Don't forget to import your image into Swift Playgrounds for iPad first.

Answer (score 0):

You should see an image icon on the keyboard to pick an image, ones you define an image variable,

```
let image: Image =
```